# mongodb kafka source connector - pipeline not working as expected

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to push to Kafka only documents from MongoDB that match specific criteria. When I don't add any configuration for the "pipeline" property, I get all the documents to be pushed to Kafka. When I add a configuration to filter for matching criteria, I get none.
Here is my connector configuration:

```
name=MongoDBSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
connector.class=com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
connection.uri=mongodb://myconnectionstring
database=mydb
collection=mycollection
publish.full.document.only=true
pipeline=[ { $match: { title: "mytitle"} } ]
copy.existing.pipeline=[ { $match: { title: "mytitle"} } ]
copy.existing=true
```

I'm following this documentation: [https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/current/kafka-source/](https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/current/kafka-source)
I get no error on Kafka Connector logs.
Any idea on what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the "". MongoDb operators should be with no quotes and fields should have it:

```
pipeline=[ { $match: { "title": "mytitle"} } ]
```

copy.existing.pipeline=[ { $match: { "title": "mytitle"} } ]

Comment: This also solved the problem for me, it's confusing because in the documentation they use quotes around the operators https://docs.mongodb.com/kafka-connector/current/source-connector/configuration-properties/copy-existing/#settings